Example of a finitely generated metabelian group whose Fitting subgroup is not nilpotent
It is known that the Fitting subgroup of a finitely generated polycyclic-by-finite group is nilpotent, but this statement is not true for the solvable group.
It is clear that both Lamplighter groups and $BS(1,k)$ groups have Fitting subgroups being infinitely generated abelian. I was wondering if there are any examples of a finitely generated metabelian group whose Fitting subgroup is not nilpotent?

The question in the body of the post is not identical to the one in the title. Is "2-step solvable" the same as metabelian? Are you looking for a finitely generated example? It's easy to find examples thatare not finitely generated.

Thanks @DerekHolt, I am looking for a finitely generated example.

Sorry I thought metabelian means $2$-step solvable.

I expect it does. I am never sure whether either or both of these classes of groups includes abelian groups, but that's not relevant to your question!

crossposed to overflow: https://mathoverflow.net/q/484533/479955
